# How does a browser calculate the size of a text-element?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how a browser calculates the width and height for a text element, for example in the following snippet, how does a browser calculate the h3 element size and also how does it resize this element when you resize the viewport ?

```css
.container-4photo {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -4%;
}

.container-4photo-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 66%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -66%);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-4photo">
  <img style="width:100%" src="https://s19.postimg.org/yt5glzp37/Diaporama4photo-1024px-379px.jpg" />

  <div class="container-4photo-text">
    <h3>La coiffure à domicile permet de gagner du temps en vous évitant le déplacementet l’attente dans le salon</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and you found nothing when searching on google ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each browser has its own default stylesheets, which specify the default properties for each element. The W3C specification for HTML5 has a set of default styles, which you can find [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html). However, there is no guarantee that every browser will adhere to them.

According to the [Sections and Headings](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#sections-and-headings) part of the specification, the default styles for headings are the following:

```
article, aside, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hgroup, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

h1 { margin-block-start: 0.67em; margin-block-end: 0.67em; font-size: 2.00em; font-weight: bold; }
h2 { margin-block-start: 0.83em; margin-block-end: 0.83em; font-size: 1.50em; font-weight: bold; }
h3 { margin-block-start: 1.00em; margin-block-end: 1.00em; font-size: 1.17em; font-weight: bold; }
h4 { margin-block-start: 1.33em; margin-block-end: 1.33em; font-size: 1.00em; font-weight: bold; }
h5 { margin-block-start: 1.67em; margin-block-end: 1.67em; font-size: 0.83em; font-weight: bold; }
h6 { margin-block-start: 2.33em; margin-block-end: 2.33em; font-size: 0.67em; font-weight: bold; }
```

As you can see, each heading has its own font size, and margin block size. Headings are blocks by default (as can be seen in the second line), hence which aspect of their margin the `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end` properties correspond to depends on their direction.

Things are simpler in the HTML4 specification, found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html), where the heading styles are as follows:

```
h1 { font-size: 2em; margin: .67em 0 }
h2 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: .75em 0 }
h3 { font-size: 1.17em; margin: .83em 0 }
h5 { font-size: .83em; margin: 1.5em 0 }
h6 { font-size: .75em; margin: 1.67em 0 }
```

Here you have simple, hard coded margins.

Comment: Thank you stybl for your answer. Accepted

Answer (score -1):

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    in pixel (32px);
    margin-block-start: 0.67em;
    in pixel(10.72px);
    margin-block-end: 0.67em;
    in pixel(10.72px);
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    color: black;
    font-family: times new roman;
    display: block;
}

for UI designing we need to remove default features of heading tags(h1-h6) use css2 universal selector* {}

. * {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You should reformat this for readability and perhaps consider some better explanatory text.